# Equating a radian to a steradian

Tags: astrophysics, geometry

I've been staring at a formula for a while now which equates an angle with a solid angle. I can see how the equation is *dimensionally* consistent, which settles well with me, but I get tripped up at the idea of equating radians with steradians. To me these are two different units.

But apparently it's common for people to mix them all up? In other words, the area of a unit hemisphere is equal to the circumference of a unit circle? See how this doesn't seem to make sense?

Now that I think about it, I suppose a radian ought to be thought of as a *ratio*, instead of areas and circumferences on unit object. 2$\pi$ radians is the ratio of *any* sized circle's circumference to its radius. 2$\pi$ steradians is the ratio of *any* sized hemisphere's area to its radius squared.

Is this the correct way of thinking about it?

Comment: In the SI, both radian and steradian are synonyms of 1. Therefore, from a purely dimensional point of view, they can be equated. Of course, the fact the an equation is dimensionally correct doesn't mean that it's physically correct: there is an infinity of quantities and just seven dimensions. To answer, it could be of help if you can post the equation and the context.

Comment: Consider a unit vector embedded in a rigid body, ${\bf e}{\tau}$. Consider that vector at some time, $t_1$. Now suppose that, at some time $t_2$, ${\bf e}(t_1) = {\bf e}(t_2)$. Let $\nu$ be the amount that the body has rotated about ${\bf e}{t_2}$ after the time interval. Let $\omega$ be the angular velocity vector. Then,  using Gauss-Bonnet theorem, we have that $\nu = \int_{t_1}^{t_2} \omega \cdot {\bf e}(\tau) d \tau + A$, where $A$ is the solid angle traced out be ${\bf e}(\tau)$.

Answer (score 1):

The unit [steradian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steradian) or [solid angle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solid_angle) are used for two-dimensional, unitless angles.  Radians are used for one-dimensional, unitless angles.  They are not the same thing.

Comment: Then how can a formula equate the two? I am very certain that the formula is not wrong.

Comment: To what formula/equation are you referring?  It may not be wrong, but there may be something that is implied that you do not see.

Comment: See my response to massimo

Comment: I have several questions for that comment.  For instance, if $\mathbf{e}(t_{1}) = \mathbf{e}(t_{2})$, then does that not imply no rotation/change has occurred in $\mathbf{e}(\tau)$?  Is $\omega$ the rate of rotation of $\mathbf{e}(\tau)$ about the center-of-mass (COM)?  Is $\mathbf{e}(\tau)$ one of the eigenvectors for the moment of inertial tensor?

Comment: Consider a body in fixed axis rotation. You can take ${\bf e}(\tau)$ to be in the direction of the axis of rotation. Then ${\bf e}(\tau)$ is fixed for all time, yet the body has still rotated about ${\bf e}(t_1) = {\bf e}(t_2)$.

Comment: This is very general. $\omega$ is just the angular velocity vector of the body and there needn't be a fixed point on the body (or a massless extension of it), i.e. it could also be translating.  ${\bf e}(\tau)$ needn't be an eigenvector of the moment of inertia tensor. It is just a material vector that gets carried with the body.

Comment: So if $\boldsymbol{\omega}$ is parallel to $\mathbf{e}$, then $A \rightarrow 0$, correct?  How can you "trace out" a solid angle when you rotate about the axis of rotation?  That equation bothers me on multiple levels.  For instance, $A$ must be a function of the angle between $\boldsymbol{\omega}$ and $\mathbf{e}$ and $\tau$, it cannot be just a constant.

Comment: $A$ in that case would be $0$ since ${\bf e}(\tau)$ traces out a point on the unit sphere. Thus, $\nu = \int_{t_1}^{t_2} \omega \cdot {\bf e} (\tau) d \tau$, which ought to make sense.

Comment: $A$ cannot be computed until ${\bf e}(\tau)$ has traversed a closed path on the unit sphere. The equation only holds when you have ${\bf e}(t_1) = {\bf e}(t_2)$ at two separate instances in time.

Comment: For a more satisfying example, take a cube in fixed axis rotation. Let ${\bf e}$ be perpendicular to $\omega$. Now try letting ${\bf e}$ be such that ${\bf e} \cdot \frac{\omega}{||\omega||} = \cos(\frac{\pi}{4}).$ I should mention here that the formula is true $\mod 2\pi$.

Comment: Check out the paper by Zhuravlev (1995): The solid angle theorem in rigid body dynamics. In particular, theorem 2.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67355/discussion-between-evan-and-honeste-vivere).

Answer (score 1):

There is a relation between radian and steradian.
$$2\pi\left(1-\cos\frac{Q}{2}\right) = \text{steradian}$$
where $Q$ is  the radian measure.  One can derive this from the volume of a sector of a sphere. Here, $Q$ ranges from $0$ to $2\pi$ radian. Angle Q is the plane angle subtended by a spherical cap at centre of a sphere. It can also be viewed in wekkipedia. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Plane angle is a base quantity with its own independent dimension: angle, **A**.  Solid angle is a derived quantity with dimension: **A**-squared.

One radian is a plane angle equal to one revolution divided by 2 pi:
rad = rev/(2 pi).

One steradian is a square radian: sr = rad-squared.

The confusion comes about because, in the SI, what is called "angle" is actually the number of radians in the angle: (actual angle)/rad.  So an SI "radian" is the number of radians in one radian: (1 rad)/rad = 1.  And the SI "solid angle" is the number of steradians in the actual solid angle.  So the SI steradian is (1 sr)/(rad-squared) = 1.

So, in this case we have one-squared = one.  No wonder there is widespread confusion permeating this subject!